# What is a good test for two variables who are roughly poissonian?

Tags: statistical-significance, poisson-distribution

I have a dataset of user answers to various questions, I compute the average number of attempts that it takes for users to get a certain question right, and I need to compare whether the "new" versions of the questions take significantly fewer attempts, on average, than the "old" versions. Right now I'm simply splitting the averages into two groups based on whether they refer to "new" or "old" versions. I can perform a direct comparison because I have a bijective mapping between old and new questions. For example, without accounting for any confounding factors, I know that about 70% of the "new" questions require, on average, fewer attempts.

The two sets of averages have distributions that look like this (superimposed, not stacked)

[image: Two Poisson-like distributions]

The "old" mean is 2.73, the "new" mean is 2.13, but they look poissonian enough to me that I'm not sure what is a good way of determining whether they are significantly different. I tried a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but I got a $p < 10^{-8}$ which sounds a bit too good to be true.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The number of attempts until an event occurs sounds a little more like a negative binomial distribution than a poisson distribution. In either case, you could try a generalized linear model (either poisson or NB) with "old vs new" as a predictor.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out NB, to be honest, but does that (or Poisson, for that matter) still hold when I compute the average number of attempts? Does it make a difference? Also, how do I do a regression analysis when the two vectors have different lengths?

Comment: Alright, I reduced the two sets to the same length, I can fit a GLM to them, but what does this tell me, exacly?

Comment: The details will depend on what statistical package you're using. By "different lengths" I'm assuming you're referring to differing sample sizes. Is that correct? The sample size does not need to be equal across groups. Also, I should have asked this earlier - are the "old" and "new" measurements performed on the group group of participants as in a pre-post design or are they independent samples?

Comment: Re package: Julia, but I'm open to R and Python, if need be. Re different lengths: yes, different sample sizes. Re old/new: for all intents and purposes, they are independent. There may be repeat participants, but we have no control over these, and we think it's unlikely enough so that they can be considered independent.